# Is there a way to simplify this Django query?

Tags: django, django-models

```
accepted_bids = Bid.objects.filter(shipment__user=u, status='acc').select_related('shipment')
completed_shipments = []
for b in accepted_bids:
    completed_shipments.append(b.shipment)
vehicles_shipped = []
for s in completed_shipments:
    vehicles_shipped.extend(s.items.all())
```

In the end, I want a list of shipped vehicles. A vehicle is shipped if it's part of a shipment that's completed. A shipment is completed if it has an accepted bid.

I'd prefer not to iterate over the querysets thereby forcing a hit to the DB before its necessary... isn't there a way to get all the associated shipments from a list of bids, for example?

---

Here's the trimmed down version of my models:

```
class Shipment(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='shipments')

class ShipmentItem(models.Model):
    shipment = ForeignKey(Shipment, related_name='items')

    class Meta:
    abstract = True

class VehicleItem(ShipmentItem):
    pass

class Bid(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='bids')
    shipment = ForeignKey(Shipment, related_name='bids')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying the schema is important. But here's a guess:

```
Vehicle.objects.filter(shipment__bid__status='acc', shipment__user=u)
```

Comment: Sorry, thought you had enough info. The problem with what you're suggesting is that "bid" is plural (a shipment can have many bids) so I don't think you can filter it like that?

Comment: So you're saying that *all* the bids for a shipment need to be accepted?

Comment: No...not at all. Only one bid can be accepted. But `shipment__bid__status` isn't a thing. It would be `shipment__bids__status`... how would that work? You need to find the vehicles that belong to shipments with an accepted bid... the "many bids" (but only one accepted) thing complicates this.

Comment: Just as written, except you'd need to change the parameter name slightly. Django's ORM mirrors SQL, so just as in SQL joining with bids that are accepted will find *any* shipment that has at least one.

Comment: Hrm... really didn't think that would work. My reasoning was that in most languages something like "user.name" makes sense, but when you have a list of users, "users.name" doesn't make sense. But I guess it's a bit different in this scenario...very cool!